# Driver is going null, not sure whats wrong. Selenium C#: Console App (.Net Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console-application

Selenium C#: Getting error "Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate. Rerun with /diag option to diagnose further."

[Project Structure: Console App (.Net Core 2.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYbFf.png)

Here is my main code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;

namespace Portal
{

    class Program
    {

        private IWebDriver driver;

        public Program()
        {
            driver = BaseDriver.GetDriver();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://Portal.com");
        }


        [Test]
        public void ExecuteTests()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("Admin");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("Admin");   
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath( 
            "html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div[4]/button/span")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Driver Class Definition:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace portal
{
    class BaseDriver
    {
        private static IWebDriver driver;

        public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\SeleniumC#\portal\portal");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
            return driver;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I got that. But, I am not getting what am I doing wrong there

Comment: What happened when you tried the suggestions at https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/122 ?

Comment: Thanks buddy, your suggestion solved my problem. Here is the fix. Added **Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk** Dependency and then did changes in properties as suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897371/compile-with-main-to-specify-the-type-that-contains-the-entry-point) suggested by user **user1585204**